# Contact App of Samsung A5(SM-A500G) become slow after software update (5.0.2)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts, samsung-galaxy-a5

After software update on my Mobile phone Samsung Galaxy A5 (SM-A500G), the Contact app become very slow to use. When I am cleaning the call log to zero then Contact app is working fine till the call log count reach the 4-5 in count. Please suggest the solution other than factory reset.

Answer (score -1):

download some contact app from play store n disable the samsung contact app in settings.

Comment: How does this resolve the issue?

Comment: How much reliable is external Contact App? Will it create any instability in the mobile? Are you suggesting any external Contact App? Thanks